# Drools rule with not condition with multiple condition causing error

Tags: drools, rule-engine

When i use below condition with 'not' I am getting an error.

```
    not(Obj1(value == 0) && Obj2(value <= 3))
```

However if i replace above condition as below I am not getting any casting exception

```
    Obj1(value != 0) or Obj2(value > 3)
```

The rule looks like this:

```
rule "test_6"
salience 10
    when
         not(Obj1(value == 0) && Obj2(value <= 3))
    then
        .....
end
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
throwing error Error Message: org.drools.core.rule.GroupElement cannot be cast to org.drools.core.rule.Pattern
```

Answer (score 1):

The `&&` and `||` operators can only be used inside a single pattern. For example: `Obj1( value > 3 && value < 10 || value == 0)`. According to [the documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-rules-WHEN-elements-ref_drl-rules), to separate Patterns, you have to use the `and` and `or` operators.

So, in your case, your rule should be:

```
rule "test_6"
salience 10
    when
         not(Obj1(value == 0) and Obj2(value <= 3))
    then
        .....
end
```

Note that it was not failing when you were using `or` because that was the right operator to use instead of `||`.

Hope it helps,